# Looking for an Object Oriented JMeter example

Tags: jmeter

I'm looking to abstract the sequence of REST calls for complicated behaviors in my company's app into a series of classes that are instantiated as needed and the methods would effectively create the sequence of HTTP request calls.  It's my hope that doing this would make the tests more compact and readable (as well as providing more reusable code).  I would need to utilize the StandardJmeterEngine and export the test to JMX format after the HashTree test plan is created.

To cut on development time, I'm hoping to find a nice example of this; I'm sure someone's done it, but I've yet to stumble onto it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking into the way of programmatic creation JMeter test take a look into the following sources:

- [JMeter API](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/)
- [How to Write a plugin for JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/extending/jmeter_tutorial.pdf)
- [Five Ways To Launch a JMeter Test without Using the JMeter GUI](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui)

If you are looking for an example project you can check out [jmeter-from-code](https://bitbucket.org/blazemeter/jmeter-from-code/src) solution which demonstrates creating a JMeter [Test Plan](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Plan) programmatically, storing it into a .jmx script file, running it and getting the .jtl results file.